# App Service IP Changing, MySQL Connection Security

Tags: mysql, azure

My app service ip address occasionally changes when I deploy new code, and the MySQL connections security does not have an option like SQL Server to allow all services in my account to access.   Does anyone have a solution for handling connection security in MySQL on azure?

Comment: Deploy to the same App Service Plan. The 4 or 5 outbound IP addresses don't change. You can get those from the portal > Web App > Properties.

Comment: I've had other IP addresses than those that are listed there.

Comment: You know the Azure SQL "Allow connections from Azure" does not mean only your account right? It means any connection from within the Azure datacenters.